# Zabbix partitioning autovacuum causes locking

Tags: postgresql, locking, autovacuum

I have a Zabbix database on a postgresql backend that grew to ~1TB of disk space. The Zabbix [housekeeper](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/administration/general) (a process for removing old data from the tables) was running for over 18 hours so I used [this](https://github.com/robbrucks/zabbix-postgresql-auto-partitioning) script to enable partitioning.

But then - exactly at midnight - Zabbix stopped inserting data into the database, right when a new partitioned table should get created.

I found out that when I kill the running autovacuum process (mostly on the table `history` or `history_uint`) via [`pg_cancel_backend()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html) the Zabbix server can insert again as some locks go away <sup>**1**</sup>.

I understand that the vacuum process is needed in order to free up transaction ID's so I should NOT do this every day.

1. Is partitioning a bad idea? (at least in an already running setup?)
2. Should I have started with partitioned tables all along?
3. Should I throw out all our monitoring data, and insert it again into correctly partitioned tables? (a huge amount of work...)
4. Should I disable autovacuum on those partitioned tables? (assuming that the issue comes from a global lock on all schemas `.public` and `.partitions`)

The final goal is to reduce the load on the database and improve performance.

By enabling partitioning I was able to reduce the runtime of the housekeeper down to a few minutes/seconds via disabling the housekeeping of `history` and `trend_data`. But it's no positive result if the monitoring stops working after midnight...

Additional Information:

The Hardware is quite oversized (all SSD and performing only OK-ish). I guess because I don't really know what knobs to tweak I better not touch them at all.

---

<sup>**1:** Unfortunately, I only figured this out 7 Hours later, in the morning. Now I have 2 days of missing monitoring data from 00:00 - 07:00</sup>

Comment: I have written an answer that should cover all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal autovacuum process will succumb silently if it blocks another transaction, but if that happens all the time and autovacuum can never finish, you will eventually have old table rows that have never been vacuumed. To prevent the danger of losing data as soon as the transaction ID counter wraps around, PostgreSQL then triggers a less benevolent autovacuum run that is *not* willing to back down.

Now creating a new partition for a table requires an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the partitioned table. Since this seems to happen every day, and autovacuum seems to run too slow to finish in one day, you end up getting stuck at midnight, when the ghosts of automatic table partitioning start rattling their chains.

Killing autovacuum is not a solution, because it will only make the problem worse. The work will be lost, and PostgreSQL will start autovacuum again, and even if you manage to silence it, eventually the database will refuse data modifications. Then your only option is to take down the database start it in single user mode and run a manual `VACUUM`. That causes a longer outage, so you don't want that.

The best solution is to tune autovacuum so that it can run as fast as possible, in the hope that it gets done within 24 hours:

- set `autovacuum_work_mem` as high as you can
- set `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay` to 0

Additionally, if you have many partitions, you should increase `autovacuum_max_workers` somewhat.

Now keep your fingers crossed and hope that autovacuum gets done before midnight.

You can monitor the state of affairs with something like

```
SELECT s.last_autovacuum, s.last_vacuum, age(t.relfrozenxid)
FROM pg_stat_all_tables AS s
   JOIN pg_class AS t ON s.relid = t.oid
WHERE age(t.relfrozenxid) > 200000000
ORDER BY age(t.relfrozenxid) DESC;
```

Keep working until that list is empty!

If you cannot get autovacuum to complete a single table in 24 hours, your only choice is to skip creating new partitions for a while (or at least not attaching them to the partitioned table).

Comment: Thank you for you excelent answer! I'll set up everything as you wrote, and will leave a comment in a few days (If I will remember ;) )

Comment: I have 2 entries in your query one for each of the tables in question and one without a "last_autovacuum" date. (both age at over 414523852) this does not seem "ok", does it?

Comment: It just means that there are 88 tables that need an anti-wraparound vacuum. PostgreSQL can treat 3 of them at the same time (unless you increase `autovacuum_max_workers`), so that will take a while. No reason for panic, you are far from wraparound. Just fix a couple of tables every day until you are good. The tables that were never vacuumed look like they need it most, so start with them.

Comment: sorry I was connected to the postgres database, not the zabbix database... I corrected my comment

Comment: The same holds for the `postgres` database. But that should get sorted out as soon as the big tables are treated.

Comment: what does ```age(t.relfrozenxid)``` do? ```relfrozenxid``` seems to be a Transaction ID, and not something you could put into the ```age``` function. At least the output seems to be a useless value.

Comment: The age of a transaction ID is the number of transactions it is in the past. So if the current txid is 100, the age of 95 is 5.

Comment: ok, after 19,5h of vacuuming i only got to about 68% ```SELECT ((heap_blks_vacuumed::numeric / heap_blks_total::numeric)::numeric * 100)::integer FROM pg_stat_progress_vacuum;``` (If that query is about right...)

Comment: Then you should delay creating the partition for a day. If you can. This needs to get done at some point.

Comment: and what if there are no changes anymore on that table? Is there a way to stop auto vacuum for that table and drop all data from the table in the public schema but keep all the partitioned tables and data?

Comment: New "Idea": I create the partitions beforehand and should therefore be able to NOT get stuck at midnight. Lets see I Created tables till the 11th of September (so 4 new partitioned Taels for each of the tables in question (history and history_uint)). Lets see what might bring up. I keep you informed (if you are still somewhat interested)

Comment: Creating the partitions in advance is the obvious solution.

Comment: It would have worked with creating the partitions beforehand, if I'd have done it right... But its finished now, so thank you for your help!

Comment: I recommend that you schedule a regulare `VACUUM` of these tables. Unfortunately autovacuum isn't very smart with insert-only tables.

Comment: That should then finish way faster, because it can skip most pages.

Comment: The Main tables are not used anymore for inserts. Zabbix works like this: it inserts all data into coresponding tables (like history (for float) history_uint (for indigent integer) and so on). Those values have a lifetime (mostly 31 days). The Zabbix Housekeeper tries to delete older values every hour. After a few Months the Table grew to big for the all the Maintainance tasks, so I switched to partitioning. The rest is the history of this post. The last time I’ll have to do this is weh.  I clear up the original table in a few weeks. (If I should do that at all...)